# Moving wordpress from TLD to sub-folder (URL structure only)

Tags: directory

I've a wordpress installation at mytld.com. So far the primary intent was to run a blog and my posts are in the format mytld.com/y/m/postname.

Now I want to shift the blog under a new URL structure mytld.com/blog/y/m/postname and instead setup a website under mytld.com by using wordpress pages.

I'm looking for suggestions / best strategy for the most effective way to do this. Also what .htaccess rules do I have to introduce to redirect all /y/m/postname --> /blog/y/m/postname so that I don't loose any link juice.

Thank you.

Comment: The most complete page on this is probably [Moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) from the WordPress Codex, have a look at it.

Comment: I think this suggestion is a good one if you intend to run two versions of WordPress.  Sounds like OP simply wants to add some pages to a blog?

Comment: have you tried this plugin?

https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

Comment: I assume that you have access to you wordpress db, so another quick way is to replace everything in your db with example.com with example.com/blog , velvet blues though takes care of the code in the files too I think.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use one WP installation and to simply add /blog/ to your permalink structure.   This will give all of your blog posts a mytld.com/blog/postname format and pages will not pickup the /blog/ prefix.

Adjust Permalink settings at Settings > Permalinks and select the Custom Structure radio button.   Enter `/blog/%postname%/` in the field and save changes.

Your category and tag archives will pick this up automatically as well.  Do not enter a prefix here unless you want additional layers in your URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a new installation to do this. You can have the WordPress files installed on the /blog/ folder and point your homepage to the site's root. Then in the settings use:
WordPress Address (URL): http://mytld.com/blog/
Site Address (URL): http://mytld.com/

Make sure to read this page, specially the "*Moving a Root install to its own directory*" section: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Make sure also to check that the old URLs are redirecting to the new location. If they aren't you will need to setup 301 redirects either in your .htaccess file or using a plugin. I like this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/